# JavaScript - Building of JSON data structure - How to change key name with variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

I am dynamically building a JSON data structure. My code works fine, but I have a problem, as I need to set the data up, then replace the key name.

I need to replace the key name below with one of my variables - the actual request type itself that I have stored in a variable.

I need to do this for the 'requestType' key below. It works fone for the values, but not for replacing the key name.

Below is my code:

```
// Create data array, used for building request message
var data = {
    requestType: { 
        item1 : null,
        item2 : null,
        item3 : null
    }
};

// Set the field array variables with data
$('input[name="item1"], [name="item2"], [name="item3"]').each(function(index) {
    if(index==0){
        data.requestType.item1 = this.value;
    } else if(index==1){
        data.requestType.item2 = this.value;
    } else if(index==2){
        data.requestType.item3 = this.value;
    }
});
```

Please help :)

Comment: @nnnnnn's answer is correct. You can't rename a property (key), only create new one or delete. So rename technically means, create new property with desired key name and copy over the values from your previous key/property.

Answer (score 4):

If you're saying that `requestType` is a variable containing some other string then you'd use this syntax:

```
data[requestType].item1 = this.value;
```

The basic principle is:

```
data.somePropertyName
// is equivalent to
data["somePropertyName"] // note the quotes
// is equivalent to
requestType = "somePropertyName"
data[requestType]
```

If you're saying you want to *change* an existing property's name then:

```
data.newPropertyName = data.requestType;
delete data.requestType;
```

Combine with the above `[]` syntax as necessary.

By the way, what you're dealing with is *not* JSON, it's an object that you're creating via an object literal. JSON is always a string representation of data (usually used for data interchange purposes) with a syntax that looks like JavaScript's object literal syntax.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is I need to actually replace the name 'RequestType' with something else - requestType1 for example

Comment: As it happens I was just adding to my answer to tell you how to change a property name. You can't really _change_ a property name, but you can add a new one that references the same thing and then delete the old.

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn this does work well when looking to change it to a different value - thanks, but my issue now is, I need the requestType to be replavced with a variable, but when I do the above, it uses the variable NAME and not the actual variable. And idea how I can pass it the actual variable value?

Comment: As I said in my answer, combine with the `[]` syntax that I explained at the beginning of the answer. `data[yourVariableHere] = data.requestType;`